# optimizing resource allocation using criterion set

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy

A dying father is interesting in divesting his estate. he has a portfolio like so:

```
AAPL : 5,000
MSFT : 10,000
AMZN : 6,000 and etc
```

we know the number of different type of stocks is finite, and the total number of stocks held is finite

He has a number of estate beneficiaries, a number unknown to us but we know it is finite.
Each beneficiary has different requirements that we know, the number of requirements are finite.

For instance:

```
Case 1:
    Charity X can only take 3,000 shares of AAPL and 6,000 share of MSFT
    Leftover  : 2,000 shares of AAPL, 4,000 shares of MSFT, 6,000 shares of AMZN

Case 2:
    Charity X can only take 3,000 shares of AAPL and 6,000 share of MSFT
    Charity Y can ony take 1,000 shares of AAPL
    Leftover  : 1,000 shares of AAPL, 4,000 shares of MSFT, 6,000 shares of AMZN
```

**Is there an algorithm that is able to:**

- return the optimal distribution of shares across 1 beneficiary, OR 2 beneficiary OR 3 beneficiaries etc
- with the minimal leftover in the original dying father's portfolio - if the type of stock requirement, and limit on number of stock of that type for each beneficiary is known?

Comment: The title of your question is "Optimizing Greedy Algorithm". I don't see an algorithm in this question.

Comment: i have a similar problem like this too...is there a way to get more users to tackle this problem?

Comment: sounds like linear programming to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: What exactly are the rules for what a beneficiary can be given? In Case 2, could X be given only 1000 shares of AAPL? Or no AAPL, but still be given 6000 MSFT?

Comment: he should have shorted all 3 stocks back in sept, then he wouldn't have to worry about this problem cause he would have enough $$$ to go around.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan in Case 2, X can requires 3,000 AAPL shares, and 6,000 MSFT. no more, no less. X requires both types of shares, in that exact quantity.

Comment: @ltjax since its LP, does it mean its unsolvable?

Comment: If it is indeed LP, there's plenty of algorithms to solve it. For example the simplex algorithm, which is explained on the wiki page...

Comment: @ltjax how do i know if it's LP, i'm guessing that it's LP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by some form of [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

It fits the definition of a linear programming problem exactly: You have a set of non-negative variables: the amounts of each stock everyone, including the "leftover" fraction gets. You have a set of constraints on them: the maximum number of shares one fraction can hold of a type. And you have a target function to maximize! The number of leftover shares should be minimized, i.e. its negative should be maximized.

I'm not a finance person, but I guess that you cannot have fractional shares. In this case, the problem gets a lot harder because all your numbers are required to be integers. This is then called "integer linear programming" (ILP). In many practical solutions, this can be [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard). However, chances are that your instance can be solved effectively if your numbers aren't too weird. ILP solvers are also well researched because a lot of problems can be mapped to them. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791559/how-to-choose-an-integer-linear-programming-solver) on SO.

Comment: hi what if assuming a simple case where it is possible to have fractional shares, is there an optimal solution?

Comment: Yes, the simplex algorithm will do then. You can also get optimal solutions if you formulate it without fractional shares, it might just take a while to compute it.